# Eliminar archivos mediante su nombre o parte de este con un .BAT

Tags: script, batch, consola

Tengo un problema relacionado con la automatización de una tarea. Necesito crear un archivo .bat que me elimine unos logs que genera una aplicación que tienen extensión .txt y esto lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
cd "C:\Users\pablo\Desktop\prueba_script" del /F /S /Q *.txt
```

La idea ahora es poder borrar esos archivos pero no por su extensión, si no por su nombre o por parte de su nombre, me explico:

Archivo:

**logArchive.txt**

**logIncidence.txt**

Necesito que el script tome parte de su nombre "**log**" y ejecute la eliminación de este...o por su nombre completo.

Comment: Te refieres a `del /F /S /Q log*.txt`?

Comment: si a ese comando en especifico me refiero mas que nada en la parte final de este y como se declara para eliminar